# How to pass SparkSession object to Kafka-Spark streaming's foreachBatch method?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a python script `loader.py` which consists of main class that creates a `sparkSession` object as given below and calls various methods to perform different actions.
from utils import extract_kafka_data, do_some_transformation

```
def main():
    try:
        spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(config['kafka_transformations']).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
        kafka_df = extract_kafka_data(spark=spark, config=config, topic_name=topic_name)
        do_some_transformation(kafka_df, spark)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f'Failed with Exception:{exc}')
        traceback.print_exc()
        print('Stopping the application')
        sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The methods extract_kafka_data, do_some_transformation are present in a different python script: utils.py
There are so many other methods inside my utils.py file that perform various transformations. Below are the couple of methods of this scenario that needs some addressing.

```
def extract_kafka_data(spark: SparkSession, config: dict, topic_name: str):
    jass_config = config['jaas_config'] + " oauth.token.endpoint.uri=" + '"' + config['endpoint_uri'] + '"' + " oauth.client.id=" + '"' + config['client_id'] + '"' + " oauth.client.secret=" + '"' + config['client_secret'] + '" ;'
    stream_df = spark.readStream \
        .format('kafka') \
        .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', config['kafka_broker']) \
        .option('subscribe', topic_name) \
        .option('kafka.security.protocol', config['kafka_security_protocol']) \
        .option('kafka.sasl.mechanism', config['kafka_sasl_mechanism']) \
        .option('kafka.sasl.jaas.config', jass_config) \
        .option('kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class', config['kafka_sasl_login_callback_handler_class']) \
        .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest') \
        .option('fetchOffset.retryIntervalMs', config['kafka_fetch_offset_retry_intervalms']) \
        .option('fetchOffset.numRetries', config['retries']) \
        .option('failOnDataLoss', 'False') \
        .option('checkpointLocation', checkpoint_location) \
        .load() \
        .select(from_json(col('value').cast('string'), schema).alias("json_dta")).selectExpr('json_dta.*')
    return stream_df

def do_some_transformation(spark: SparkSession, kafka_df: Dataframe):
    kafka_df.writeStream \
        .format('kafka') \
        .foreachBatch(my_transformation_method) \
        .option('checkpointLocation', checkpoint_location) \
        .trigger(processingTime='10 minutes') \
        .start()
        .awaitTermination()

def my_transformation_method(kafka_df: Dataframe, batch_id: int):
    base_delta = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, config['delta_path'])
    base_delta.alias("base") \
        .merge(source=kafka_df.alias("inc"), condition=build_update_condition(config['merge_keys'], config['inc_keys'])) \
        .whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
        .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
        .execute()
```

The problem I am facing here is with the method: `my_transformation_method`.
Inside method: `my_transformation_method` I am performing a merge of my kafka dataframe with my delta table.
In order to read the base table data, I need to run this statement:
base_delta = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, config['delta_path'])
But the problem here is that the method: `my_transformation_method` which is being called by `foreachBatch` in `do_some_transformation` method can only receive two method arguments: 1. Dataframe 2. batch_id as per the syntax of spark streaming.

I can make the spark session object global but I don't want to do it as it doesn't appear to be the standard way.
Is there any way I can make the sparkSession object `spark` available to method `my_transformation_method` when I call it from `do_some_transformation` ?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can pass as many arguments as you want... Are you looking for something like `foreachBatch(lambda (df, id): my_transformation_method(spark, df, id))`? Alternatively, why isn't `base_delta` defined outside that function if your config never changes?

Comment: `foreachBatch(lambda (df, id): my_transformation_method(spark, df, id))` This cant work because the dataframe is split into smaller batches and that batch of data in the dataframe is passed. So I can't pass `kafka_df` as an argument to `my_transformation_method` like this: 
`kafka_df.writeStream.format('kafka')
.foreachBatch(lambda df, id: my_transformation_method(spark, kafka_df, id)) \
.option('checkpointLocation', checkpoint_location) \
.trigger(processingTime='10 minutes') \
.start()
.awaitTermination()`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 
"I can make the spark session object global but I don't want to do it as it doesn't appear to be the standard way."

In a Spark app you usually have a "session.py" or whatever module in which you define 

"spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=spark_conf).getOrCreate()"

which is a singleton and import / use wherever needed.

"from myapp.session import spark"

Some people use DI libs or frameworks but it's absolutely not needed for clean code.

Comment: It is because there are almost 20 other methods that receive spark session as an argument. I don't want to create a SparkSesison in every .py script or simply create global variables in every method to initialize them and make the script confusing.

Comment: Well, thats actually the thing: you don't. Take numpy as example: "import numpy as np".
You don't pass "np" as an argument in every method, you juste use "np.method" in you code. Spark session is no different.

Comment: You don't even need it as a parameter, thus the "get" in `getOrCreate`

Comment: there is also `SparkSession.getActiveSession()`

Answer (score 1):

DataFrame API ptovides sparkSession method that can be used:

```
spark = kafka_df.sparkSession()
```